# How to get the cumulative sum of column by group when some group missing in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, cumulative-sum, group

I have a large dataframe with 4 columns(date,location,type,NOV) ,
I would like to calculate the cumulative value for NOV column for each date with all groups.

my data frame:

date                     location           type          NOV

27.12.2020                x               a             2

27.12.2020                x               b             3

27.12.2020                y               a             1

27.12.2020                y               b             1

27.12.2020                z               a             1

27.12.2020                z               b             3

28.12.2020                x               a             4

28.12.2020                y               a             2

28.12.2020                y               b             1

28.12.2020                z               b             3

29.12.2020                x               a             1

29.12.2020                x               b             2

29.12.2020                y               a             2

29.12.2020                z               b             4

I want this output:

date                    location          type           NOV  CUMSUM NOV

27.12.2020                x               a             2       2

27.12.2020                x               b             3       3

27.12.2020                y               a             1       1

27.12.2020                y               b             1       1

27.12.2020                z               a             1       1

27.12.2020                z               b             3       3

28.12.2020                x               a             4       6

28.12.2020                x               b             0       3

28.12.2020                y               a             2       3

28.12.2020                y               b             1       2

28.12.2020                z               a             0       1

28.12.2020                z               b             3       6

29.12.2020                x               a             1       7

29.12.2020                x               b             2       5

29.12.2020                y               a             2       5

29.12.2020                y               b             0       2

29.12.2020                z               a             0       1

29.12.2020                z               b             4       10

I am using this code but this does not give what I want :

'''

```
            d-new <- df %>% 
              group_by(location,type) %>% 
              mutate(CUMSUM NOV = cumsum(NOV))
```

'''

however this code only calculates the cumulative value for groups that are present on the date, if one group is missing on one date, it does not include the previous data of that group in the cumulative sum.

Is there any better approach for solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `complete` to fill in missing `date` values, and specify `fill` to use 0 for `NOV` for these missing dates. I added `arrange` at the end to sort and make sure appears equivalent to desired data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  complete(location, type, date, fill = list(NOV = 0)) %>%
  group_by(location, type) %>% 
  mutate(CUMSUM_NOV = cumsum(NOV)) %>%
  arrange(date)
```

**Output**

```
   location type  date         NOV CUMSUM_NOV
   <chr>    <chr> <chr>      <int>      <int>
 1 x        a     27.12.2020     2          2
 2 x        b     27.12.2020     3          3
 3 y        a     27.12.2020     1          1
 4 y        b     27.12.2020     1          1
 5 z        a     27.12.2020     1          1
 6 z        b     27.12.2020     3          3
 7 x        a     28.12.2020     4          6
 8 x        b     28.12.2020     0          3
 9 y        a     28.12.2020     2          3
10 y        b     28.12.2020     1          2
11 z        a     28.12.2020     0          1
12 z        b     28.12.2020     3          6
13 x        a     29.12.2020     1          7
14 x        b     29.12.2020     2          5
15 y        a     29.12.2020     2          5
16 y        b     29.12.2020     0          2
17 z        a     29.12.2020     0          1
18 z        b     29.12.2020     4         10
```